# Write the correct format of JSON to file using json.dumps() in Python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

Let say I have a simple dictionary as below:

```
a = {'animal' : 'fish', 'fruit' : 'apple','vehicle' : 'car'}
```

I wish to convert `a` into JSON and write to a file. If I used `json.dumps()` as below:

```
b = jason.dumps(a) 
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(pprint.pformat(b))
```

The content of the JSON file `output.json` became:

```
'{"animal": "fish", "fruit": "apple", "vehicle": "car"}'
```

What I wish to actually have (in the file) is without quote as below:

```
{"animal": "fish", "fruit": "apple", "vehicle": "car"}
```

What is the right way to code it so that I can get the desired output?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]: The reason why I need the desired output in file is because I received the error below when I loaded the file.

```
>>> with open("output.json") as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/louis.kok/Analyses/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Users/louis.kok/Analyses/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/louis.kok/Analyses/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/louis.kok/Analyses/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: This is a valid JSON string `'{"animal": "fish", "fruit": "apple", "vehicle": "car"}'
`. Why do you need it without quotes? While reading it use `json.loads()` @bison72

Comment: @Vishnudev I have edited my question. I received error when loading the file but without the quote, I can load it.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `json` library

```
import json
```

Save your file properly using `json.dump`

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(a, f)
```

Read it using `json.load`

```
with open("output.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
with open('task.json', 'w') as f:
    s = json.dumps(mydict, indent=2)
    f.write('%s\n' % (s))
```